# Changing boot order/booting from USB

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb, kali-linux

I have the kali-linux-1.0.6-amd64 downloaded on my desktop and have used "Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2" to install this on my Usb. With it completed and the Usb plugged into my computer. I then pressed f10 repeatedly (I'm on a windows 7 Hp) to get to a blue and grey set-up utility. From here I navigated to my boot order and moved all options mentioning usb to the top.(A total of 4 options were moved) When I boot it still boots strait into windows... Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

P.s. Please don't hesitate to post anything even if its redundant.

Comment: What is the brand/model of the computer you are attempting this on? Various brands (Lenovo, Dell) have more than one boot order that you can set.

Comment: You may need to change the order of 'hard drives' that it boots up. Some computers have USB sticks present as hard drives.

Comment: I'm using a Hp Windows 7 and it uses intel i5

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you created a **bootable** USB drive. Try this utility: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

If that is correct then try removing the hard disk as a boot option, and CD-ROM as well leaving only the USB drive.

Comment: I used a trusted bootable USB drive maker I will try this one and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Please `Enable boot from external devices` after that put `USB or Removable devices` at first priority then you will be able to boot from USB.

and once again check your bootable Pendrive when you plug in it in `windows 7` it will show the linux icon on USB that means your USB is bootable.

hope this will work..